# Extract only time from database where time is saving along with date in gridview

Tags: sql, vb.net

What should I use to get only time in gridview

I want to fetch only `03:42` but getting `01-01-1900 03:42:00` how to do this

This is code

```
cmd.CommandText = "select bumker1 Bumker_1, bumker2 Bumker_2, bumker3 Bumker_3, silo Silo_No, start_time Drier_Strt_Time,
                   end_time End_Time, hexa_resol Hexa_Sol_Prep, hexa_used Hexa_Used, batch_coated Coated_Batch, resin_used Resin_Used, sand_quantity Make 
                   from mm_sandPreparation s 
                   where date='" & Format(CDate(sanddate.Text), "MM/dd/yyyy") & "' and shift='" & rblshift.SelectedValue & "' "
Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
   sda.SelectCommand = cmd
   Using dt As New DataSet()
       sda.Fill(dt)
       vw_sand_details.DataSource = dt
       vw_sand_details.DataBind()
   End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETUTCDATE(), 108)
```

will return the output in `HH:MM` format as `07:26`

So in your query

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), start_time, 108)
```

will return the datetime into `HH:MM` format